# MIPS Sum of a number of double in input

Tags: mips

how can I obtain the sum of a number of double inserted through keyboard and saved in the stack?
This is my code, but, give me this output:
0.0

```
load_number:
move $t0, $a0 
move $t1, $a1
#counter
li $t2,0

while:
    beq $t2, $t1, end_load
    #read a double
    li $v0, 7
    syscall
    #save in the stack
    swc1 $f0, ($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, -4
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    #Repeat
    j while

 ............

while_sum:
    beq $t2, $t1, end_sum
    lwc1  $f2, ($t0)
    add.d $f4, $f4, $f2
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j while_sum

end_sum:

    li $v0, 3
    mov.d $f12, $f4
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

A double is 8 bytes, not 4. So you need to adjust your address increments, and use `ldc1`/`sdc1` instead of `lwc1`/`swc1`.

Comment: Hi Michael and thanks for the answer. I have adjusted the number of bytes for the stack but, when I use ldc1 or sdc1 Mars give me this error:  
Runtime exception at 0x00400080: address not aligned on doubleword boundary 0x7fffefec
at the line of ldc1 or sdc1. If I use lwc1 or swc1 I obtain this: 1.273197475E-314 if I add 3.20+3.20 Can you help me?

Comment: Then you need to make sure that the address is double-word aligned. It's unclear where the address comes from originally. If it's an array declared in the `.data` section you should preceed it with `.align 3`

Comment: I have asked from the keyboard a number, multiply this for 8 and subtract the result at the stack, all in the .text section. The address is passed at the function by convention ---> move $a0, $sp for example.

Comment: Well, you want it to be a multiple of 16. So use `sub` or `and` to ensure that the 4 least significant bits are zeroes. And make sure to restore `$sp` to its original value once your down with your array.

Comment: Mmmm... I haven't understand my friend... If for 3 numbers I subtract at the stack 24 byte and try to save on it with ldc1, why Mars give me an error of not alligned doubleword? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you subtract 24 from something that isn't double-word aligned to begin with you end up with something that also isn't double-word aligned. You need to make sure that the address is aligned on 8 bytes before you start writing to it.

Comment: I can't do this thing :/